# sending a string from QT to Arduino

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

I'm trying to send a string from qt application to arduino , at first I sent a simple character and it's worked, but when I try to take a string from my `Linedit` and send it to the arduino via serial port , it show me an error:

> erreur : no matching function for call to QSerialPort::write(QString&)

this the code

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()

{
QString envoi ;

envoi = ui->lineEdit->text();

/* ui->label->setText(envoi); */


  serial.setPortName("com17");

    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);

    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);

    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);

    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);

    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    serial.write(envoi);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three `write` methods available in `QSerialPort` all of which are inherited from `QIODevice`

```
qint64 QIODevice::write(const char * data, qint64 maxSize)
qint64 QIODevice::write(const char * data) // equivalent to QIODevice::write(data, qstrlen(data));
```

and lastly

```
qint64 QIODevice::write(const QByteArray & byteArray)
```

You have a couple of possibilities to make your write call, the most simple to me seems

```
serial.write(envoi.toUtf8());
```

which uses

```
QByteArray QString::toUtf8()
```

You can also use convoluted things like

```
serial.write(envoi.toStdString.c_str() );
```

which would then use the `write(const char * data)` method.

Let me know if this helps.